# Db on the EC2, how many EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have an EC2 instance on which I want to install Postgresql using Docker.
Is it advisable to have two EBS connected, one root and one for data? Or could just a single one be enough? And for what reason?

In both cases, take periodic EBS snapshots.

Comment: I would say recommended would be to use RDS, otherwise I would recommend a dedicated data volume to make backup and IOPs scaling easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is advised to have the Postgresql data on a specific storage.

That way it simplifies the upgrade for instance, you change just the AMI and start a new EC2.

You should consider running your DB with RDS.

Comment: I can't use RDS because not support a specific extension that I use

Comment: @FedericoGovoni Which extension is that?

Comment: @jordanm plpython3u, at the moment, we can't substitute it

Comment: @FedericoGovoni While I don't think it's that specific extension, Amazon Redshift (postgres), does have similar functionality: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html

Comment: @jordanm yes, but we need that specific one for the moment